# Eclipse Modeling Framework and XPAND - How to create iOS metamodel?

Tags: ios, modeling, eclipse-emf-ecore, model-driven-development, xpand

I want to define a model driven approach with Eclipse Modeling Framework (EMF) and XPAND. Therefore I want to define a platform specific metamodel (PSM) with Ecore and write XPAND templates for code generation for the iOS platform.

My question is this:

Is it possible to define such a PSM for the iOS platform in EMF? Because iOS or other platforms have own data types. I can also define data types with `EDataType` but they have to be related to the Java data types?

Answer (score 2):

It's better to ask on the Eclipse eclipse.tools.emf forum...

Ecore itself is tightly bound to Java so is already a PSM for EMF's Java-based core runtime.  You're likely better off defining your own Ecore-like model for iOS (using Ecore to define that model just as Ecore is used to define itself and other models like UML2 and XSD).  And you're also likely better off using the new Xtext-based Xtend language than the older Xpand technology because it has better support and much better tools, e.g., integration with JDT and JDT's debugger so you can seamlessly debug your Xtend template source in your normal debugger.